# Inline functions call Code Composer 5.4.0

Tags: inline, code-composer

I am suffering with a bizarre issue came up in the code am working in Code Composer.
That is,in the code am working on there are some inline functions called,through an .inl file.Everything seem fine so far,the problem comes when instead of calling and executing that function,a Visual studio (or other default program for defined for editing your code) comes up and in the screen and the pointer passed to the function becomes null while it was not...
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the disassembly for your code. The assembly for the inline function should be directly inserted there. Check to see if that is happening. If not, it is your compiler that has an issue.
Why don't you try putting the inline functions in a .hpp file and see if you get the same problem?